# Как задать объекту класса свойства?

Tags: php

Имеется класс с тремя свойствами: цвет, тип, модель. Каким образом задать эти свойства (с помощью функции?), чтобы при выводе на экран команды с объектом класса var_dump($Honda) выводились эти свойства (строковые значения)?

```
class Car

{

protected $type;
protected $color;
protected $model;

public function __construct($type, $color, $model)

{

$this->type = $type;
$this->color = $color;
$this->model = $model;

}

public function setParameters($color)
{ 
    $color = 'green';
    $type = 'sportcar';
    $model = 'A21';
}
}


$AstonM = new Car();
$Honda = new Car();


var_dump($Honda);
```

Comment: Сделайте функцию `getParameters()` и пусть она выводит то что вам нужно. В таком форме, который вам нужен.

Comment: если вы про `setParameters` то там явно не хватает `$this` внутри

Comment: @teran можете правку внести с $this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас конструктор принимает аргументы. Используйте их.

```
$AstonM = new Car( 'Aston', 'red', '10' );
$Honda = new Car( 'Honda', 'blue', 'Civic' );
```

Если хотите убрать из конструктора и пользоваться функцией, то так:

```
class Car
{
    protected $color;
    protected $type;
    protected $model;

    public function setParameters($color, $type, $model)
    {
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->model = $model;
    }
}


$AstonM = new Car();
$AstonM->setParameters('green', 'sportcar', 'A21');

$Honda = new Car();
$Honda->setParameters('blue', 'hatchback', 'Civic');


var_dump($AstonM);
var_dump($Honda);
```

Comment: а если убрать аргументы из конструктора и с помощью функции. как это пишется?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.